# MassTransit with RabbitMq Request/Response wrong reply address because of network segments

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a web app that uses a request/response message in Masstransit.
This works on out test environment, no problem.

However on the customer deployment we face a problem. At the customer site we do have two network segments A and B. The component doing the database call is in segment A, the web app and the RabbitMq server in segment B.

Due to security restrictions the component in segment A has to go through a loadbalancer with a given address. The component itself can connect to RabbitMQ with Masstransit. So far so good.

The web component on segment B however uses the direct address for the RabbitMq server. When the web component now is starting the request/response call, I can see that the message arrives at the component in segment A. 
However I see that the consumer tries to call the RabbitMQ server on the "wrong" address. It uses the address the web component uses to issue the request. However the component in segment A should reply on the "loadbalancer" address.

Is there a way to configure or tell the RespondAsync call to use the connection address configured for that component?

Of course the easiest would be to have the web component also connect through the loadbalancer, but due to the network segments/security setup the loadbalancer is only reachable from segment A.

Any input/help is appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar issue but with different configuration. I have federated rabbitmq hosts and request is done on one host while response comes from another. Naturally bus URIs for requester and respondent are different so respondent fails trying to respond to "wrong" URI.

Comment: Have you trying manipulating the request headers to the ReplyAddress has different host name?

Comment: I've tried using `ConfigureSend(c => c.UseSendFilter(new ReplaceResponseUriWithRelative(hostUriString))` to replace `ResponseAddress` with relative URI upon sending, so that it could be converted to a different absolute URI on the receive side. But when the filter is called `ResponseAddress` is still null. When I provided a callback to `MessageRequestClient` client `ResponseAddress` was there, but if I modify it to relative the consumer cannot parse it from the envelope as it expects absolute.

Comment: @alpha-mouse: Thanks for the tip with the UseSendFilter. I thought I had it solved with that one. Unfortunately when doing the `context.RespondAsync` the return address seems to be checked first against the list with the known hosts. Thus the error is raised before the message is actually sent and before the SendFilter is reached, where I would have been able to change the `ResponseAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with rabbitmq federation. Here's what I did.

#### ResponseAddressSendObserver

```
class ResponseAddressSendObserver : ISendObserver
{
    private readonly string _hostUriString;

    public ResponseAddressSendObserver(string hostUriString)
    {
        _hostUriString = hostUriString;
    }

    public Task PreSend<T>(SendContext<T> context)
        where T : class
    {
        if (context.ResponseAddress != null)
        {
            // Send relative response address alongside the message
            context.Headers.Set("RelativeResponseAddress",
                context.ResponseAddress.AbsoluteUri.Substring(_hostUriString.Length));
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    ...
}
```

#### ResponseAddressConsumeFilter

```
class ResponseAddressConsumeFilter : IFilter<ConsumeContext>
{
    private readonly string _hostUriString;

    public ResponseAddressConsumeFilter(string hostUriString)
    {
        _hostUriString = hostUriString;
    }

    public Task Send(ConsumeContext context, IPipe<ConsumeContext> next)
    {
        var responseAddressOverride = GetResponseAddress(_hostUriString, context);

        return next.Send(new ResponseAddressConsumeContext(responseAddressOverride, context));
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context){}

    private static Uri GetResponseAddress(string host, ConsumeContext context)
    {
        if (context.ResponseAddress == null)
            return context.ResponseAddress;

        object relativeResponseAddress;
        if (!context.Headers.TryGetHeader("RelativeResponseAddress", out relativeResponseAddress) || !(relativeResponseAddress is string))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Message has ResponseAddress but doen't have RelativeResponseAddress header");

        return new Uri(host + relativeResponseAddress);
    }
}
```

#### ResponseAddressConsumeContext

```
class ResponseAddressConsumeContext : BaseConsumeContext
{
    private readonly ConsumeContext _context;

    public ResponseAddressConsumeContext(Uri responseAddressOverride, ConsumeContext context)
        : base(context.ReceiveContext)
    {
        _context = context;
        ResponseAddress = responseAddressOverride;
    }

    public override Uri ResponseAddress { get; }

    public override bool TryGetMessage<T>(out ConsumeContext<T> consumeContext)
    {
        ConsumeContext<T> context;
        if (_context.TryGetMessage(out context))
        {
            // the most hackish part in the whole arrangement
            consumeContext = new MessageConsumeContext<T>(this, context.Message);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            consumeContext = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    // all other members just delegate to _context 
}
```

And when configuring the bus

```
var result = MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(hostAddress), h =>
    {
        h.Username(...);
        h.Password(...);
    });

    cfg.UseFilter(new ResponseAddressConsumeFilter(hostAddress));

    ...
});
result.ConnectSendObserver(new ResponseAddressSendObserver(hostAddress));
```

So now *relative* response addresses are sent with the messages and used on the receiving side.

Using *observers* to modify anything is not recommended by the documentation, but should be fine in this case.

Maybe three is a better solution, but I haven't found one. HTH

Comment: Thanks for the input @alpha-mouse. Will need to check the solution tomorrow. 
In the meantime a new idea came up. Maybe I can solve my problem using the host file and add the "external" address on the internal "servers". Currently the external loadbalancer uses port 443 which is the redirected to 5672. If I can get the network guys to change the port, then the host file solution might be the easiest setup.